# What is difference between the ternary model= y ? y : 'see' ; and model = y ? 'see' : ' '; in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a script

```
model.setAsDefault = content.setAsDefault ? content.setAsDefault : 'selected';
```

and

```
model.setAsDefault = content.setAsDefault ? 'selected' : '';
```

I want to know the difference between these two syntaxes

Comment: I think you want `==`.

Comment: they are the same syntax, but there is a difference. one sets the value to `content.setAsDefault` or `'selected'` - the other sets it to `'selected'` or `''` - i.e. completely and utterly different results

Comment: @Dai - where would `==` even be appropriate?

Comment: @Dai It depends - he may just be doing a conditional assignment to `model.setAsDefault`

Comment: There are no differences between the syntaxes of those two expressions. They just have different values.

Comment: I am not sure this post meets the criteria for a stack overflow question

Comment: @JessicaPennell why does it not?

Comment: @JessicaPennell, yeah it feels more like "I have homework, but I don't understand a word of it"

Comment: @Bravo the `==` would be appropriate if OP was checking both values were equivalent, and assigning a value accordingly - given the context (or lack thereof), that probably isn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference in the syntax.
The difference is in the logic.

For the first one.

```
model.setAsDefault = content.setAsDefault ? content.setAsDefault : 'selected';
```

You are determining if `content.setAsDefault` is truthy and then assigning it's value to `model.setAsDefault`. If it's not truthy, it will set `model.setAsDefault` to the `'selected'`

The second expression

```
model.setAsDefault = content.setAsDefault ? 'selected' : '';
```

Also checks the truthiness of `content.setAsDefault` but now you are assigning the `'selected'` to `model.selAsDefault` if it is truthy otherwise the blank string.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode for case 1 :

```
Assign to model.setAsDefault the following :
    Does content.setAsDefault already have a non-false value?
        Yes : Set model.setAsDefault to the existing non-false value stored in content.setAsDefault
        No : Set model.setAsDefault to the hard coded string "selected"
```

Pseudocode for case 2 :

```
Assign to model.setAsDefault the following :
    Does content.setAsDefault already have a non-false value?
        Yes : set model.setAsDefault to the hard coded string "selected"
        No : set model.setAsDefault to an empty string
```